# Messaging gems for rails with the ability to group messages by threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, messaging

I have a rails 3 application. I want to add a internal messaging system with the following features:

- Users have many messages (sent and received)
- To send a message, a user can type one or many emails in the "To" field. Each email is autocompleted (this doesn't need to be in the gem)
- Messages can be marked as read, unread, and trashed
- Messages are grouped by threads: If Bob sends a message to Alice, and Alice replies, and then Bob replies again, Bob only sees one entry in his inbox for this conversation. (much like Gmail)

Do you know any Gem that would help me do that ?

One of the most popular is Mailboxer (https://github.com/ging/mailboxer). But I don't like the model too much (notifications instead of message, conversation instead of thread, receipts table...). So I'm interested in alternatives.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/User_Messaging_Systems

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest to make association as follow

```
​​class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :messages_received, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key=> 'to_user_id'
       has_many :messages_sent, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key=> 'from_user_id'
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => 'User' # from_user_id field fk Users
    belongs_to :to_user, :class_name => 'User' # to_user_id field fk Users
    belongs_to :thread, :class_name => 'Message' # Reference to parent message
    has_many :replies, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'thread_id'
end​​
```

​you can create message as follow​s

```
first_msg = Message.new(:to_user => ​userA, :from_user => ​userB, :body => 'Hello!')

​userA​_reply = first_msg.replies.build(:to_user => ​userA, :from_user => ​user​B​, :body => 'hi back')

​userB​_reply = first_msg.replies.build(:to_user => ​user​B​, :from_user => ​userA, :body => 'later')
```

​and also it will be easier to check the user sent messages as @user.messages_sent

and received as @user.messages_received

a) You can use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for auto-complete emails

b) You can use Boolean fields read, unread, and trashed